# Submitting field to database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an image slider and every time the next image is loaded I need to save a record to the database. I am trying to accomplish this using jQuery and AJAX.

I write the info I need to a hidden field called data so I can post it to my PHP page.

```
    function ajaxSave(){
        $("#data").val($("#image").attr("src")+","+ratings[iCount]);
        //alert($("#data").val());//Testing
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajaxSave.php",
            data: $("#data").val(),

            success: function(data){
                alert(data);//only for testing purposes
            }
        });
    }
```

I call my ajaxSave() function every time the next button is pressed. I get my alert that was successful but my question is: What is the $_POST[''] array cell for this?

I need to manipulate the data in the php page (see below), but I only get an alert that says "array (    )".

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

I'm very new to AJAX so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for the Ajax should be sent as a map..

So instead of

```
data: $("#data").val(),
```

Try

```
data: { 'param' : $("#data").val() },
```

Comment: Thank you! Donald beat you to it, but I do appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup the data :

```
   function ajaxSave(){
        $("#data").val($("#image").attr("src")+","+ratings[iCount]);
        //alert($("#data").val());//Testing
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/ajaxSave.php",
          data: {"requestName":$("#data").val(), 'param2':'hello World'},

          success: function(data){
             alert(data);//only for testing purposes
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are a scholar and a saint! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The data must be Key/Value pair with JSON format. For example:

```
{ username:"JhoneD", address: "and address of JhonD", city: "Boston" }
```